# Streaming USB Webcam to YouTube Live - Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, youtube, ffmpeg

all new here. Hoping someone can help.

I am trying to Stream a USB webcam to YouTube Live Events but having difficulty. I followed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947639/how-to-stream-on-youtube-using-a-raspberry-pi?newreg=31e453ff9d1549bc8addc97258127f5a

I have managed to get ffmpeg compiled and can run

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v     libx264 -b:v 700k -an -f flv rtmp://<youtube_rtmp_server/<youtube_live_stream_id>
```

It looks to me as the stream is working as I get the:

```
frame= 29 fps= 29 q=28.0 12kb time=00:00.05 bitrate=1189.0kbits
```

messages scrolling along however YouTube says "We are not receiving data from your encoder. Please make sure it is configured correctly in the Ingestion Settings page." While also saying "Good Health".

Can someone please assist? Thanks

Edit: Some logs

```
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=21 speed=   0x
frame=    2 fps=2.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=29 speed=   0x
Past duration 0.994804 too large
frame=   10 fps=6.6 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=30 speed=   0x
frame=   17 fps=8.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=30 speed=   0x
frame=   25 fps=9.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=30 speed=   0x 
frame=   32 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=30 speed=   0x 
frame=   40 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=30 speed=   0x
frame=   47 fps=8.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=30 speed=   0x
frame=   54 fps=8.8 q=24.0 size=      44kB time=00:00:02.12 bitrate= 169.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
Past duration 0.932655 too large
frame=   58 fps=8.1 q=16.0 size=     114kB time=00:00:02.33 bitrate= 401.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   61 fps=7.8 q=12.0 size=     283kB time=00:00:02.54 bitrate= 910.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s 
frame=   62 fps=7.3 q=11.0 size=     360kB time=00:00:02.58 bitrate=1141.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s    
frame=   63 fps=6.9 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   63 fps=6.6 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=67 s
frame=   63 fps=6.2 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=75 s    
frame=   63 fps=5.9 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=83 s
frame=   63 fps=5.7 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=90 s
frame=   63 fps=5.4 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=98 s
frame=   63 fps=5.2 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=105 
frame=   63 fps=5.0 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=113 
frame=   63 fps=4.8 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=120 
frame=   63 fps=4.6 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=128 
frame=   63 fps=4.5 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=136
frame=   63 fps=4.3 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=143  
frame=   63 fps=4.2 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=151 
frame=   63 fps=4.0 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=158 
frame=   63 fps=3.9 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=166 
frame=   63 fps=3.8 q=13.0 size=     414kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1269.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=173
```

more logs

```
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   49 fps= 13 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=20 speed=   0x
frame=   49 fps= 12 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=28 speed=   0x
frame=   61 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=      72kB time=00:00:00.54 bitrate=1090.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   56 fps= 12 q=26.0 size=      50kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=1976.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   65 fps= 11 q=22.0 size=     101kB time=00:00:00.79 bitrate=1046.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   69 fps= 10 q=20.0 size=     145kB time=00:00:01.08 bitrate=1097.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   73 fps=9.7 q=20.0 size=     213kB time=00:00:01.33 bitrate=1307.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   78 fps=9.7 q=22.0 size=     291kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate=1431.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   79 fps=9.2 q=22.0 size=     301kB time=00:00:01.70 bitrate=1442.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   85 fps=9.0 q=23.0 size=     365kB time=00:00:02.12 bitrate=1407.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 s
frame=   91 fps=9.1 q=24.0 size=     402kB time=00:00:02.54 bitrate=1295.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=31 s
frame=   94 fps=8.8 q=24.0 size=     425kB time=00:00:02.70 bitrate=1285.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=33 s
frame=   98 fps=8.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=51 s
frame=   98 fps=8.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=73 s
frame=   98 fps=8.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=80 s
frame=   98 fps=7.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=88 s
frame=   98 fps=7.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=95 s
frame=   98 fps=7.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=103 
frame=   98 fps=6.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=110 
frame=   98 fps=6.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=118 
frame=   98 fps=6.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=126 
frame=   98 fps=6.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=133 
frame=   98 fps=6.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=141 
frame=   98 fps=5.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=148 
frame=   98 fps=5.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=156 
frame=   98 fps=5.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=164 
frame=   98 fps=5.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=171 
frame=   98 fps=5.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=179 
frame=   98 fps=5.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=186 
frame=   98 fps=5.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=194 
frame=   98 fps=4.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=202 
frame=   98 fps=4.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=209 
frame=   98 fps=4.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=217
frame=   98 fps=4.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=224 
frame=   98 fps=4.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=232 
frame=   98 fps=4.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=239 
frame=   98 fps=4.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=247 
frame=   98 fps=4.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=255 
frame=   98 fps=4.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=262 
frame=   98 fps=4.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=270 
frame=   98 fps=3.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=277 
frame=   98 fps=3.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=285 
frame=   98 fps=3.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=293 
frame=   98 fps=3.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=300 
frame=   98 fps=3.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=308 
frame=   98 fps=3.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=315 
frame=   98 fps=3.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=323 
frame=   98 fps=3.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=331 
frame=   98 fps=3.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=338 
frame=   98 fps=3.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=346 
frame=   98 fps=3.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=353 
frame=   98 fps=3.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=361 
frame=   98 fps=3.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=368 
frame=   98 fps=3.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=376 
frame=   98 fps=3.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=384 
frame=   98 fps=3.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=391 
frame=   98 fps=2.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=399 
frame=   98 fps=2.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=406 
frame=   98 fps=2.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=414 
frame=   98 fps=2.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=422 
frame=   98 fps=2.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=429 
frame=   98 fps=2.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=437 
frame=   98 fps=2.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=444 
frame=   98 fps=2.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=452 
frame=   98 fps=2.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=459 
frame=   98 fps=2.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=467 
frame=   98 fps=2.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=475 
frame=   98 fps=2.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=482 
frame=   98 fps=2.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=490 
frame=   98 fps=2.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=497 
frame=   98 fps=2.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=505 
frame=   98 fps=2.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=513 
frame=   98 fps=2.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=520 
frame=   98 fps=2.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=528 
frame=   98 fps=2.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=535 
frame=   98 fps=2.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=543 
frame=   98 fps=2.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=551 
frame=   98 fps=2.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=558 
frame=   98 fps=2.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=566 
frame=   98 fps=2.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=573 
frame=   98 fps=2.2 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=581 
frame=   98 fps=2.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=588 
frame=   98 fps=2.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=596 
frame=   98 fps=2.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=604 
frame=   98 fps=2.1 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=611 
frame=   98 fps=2.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=619 
frame=   98 fps=2.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=626 
frame=   98 fps=2.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=634 
frame=   98 fps=2.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=642 
frame=   98 fps=2.0 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=649 
frame=   98 fps=1.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=657 
frame=   98 fps=1.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=664 
frame=   98 fps=1.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=672 
frame=   98 fps=1.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=680 
frame=   98 fps=1.9 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=687 
frame=   98 fps=1.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=695 
frame=   98 fps=1.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=702 
frame=   98 fps=1.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=710 
frame=   98 fps=1.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=717 
frame=   98 fps=1.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=725 
frame=   98 fps=1.8 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=733 
frame=   98 fps=1.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=740 
frame=   98 fps=1.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=748 
frame=   98 fps=1.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=755 
frame=   98 fps=1.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=763
frame=   98 fps=1.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=778 
frame=   98 fps=1.7 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=786 
frame=   98 fps=1.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=793
frame=   98 fps=1.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=808 
frame=   98 fps=1.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=816 
frame=   98 fps=1.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=824 
frame=   98 fps=1.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=831 
frame=   98 fps=1.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=839 
frame=   98 fps=1.6 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=846 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=854 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=862 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=869 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=877 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=884 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=892 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=900 
frame=   98 fps=1.5 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=907 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=915 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=922 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=930 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=937 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=945 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=953 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=960 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=968 
frame=   98 fps=1.4 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=975
frame=   98 fps=1.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=991 
frame=   98 fps=1.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=998 
frame=   98 fps=1.3 q=20.0 size=     453kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1237.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=1006
```

Comment: Please provide us more of the log as you are streaming.

Comment: Hi, currently just my bedroom as a test before I attempt to stream a local community program in a few days. I am using a logitech c910 hd 1080p webcam for the stream. - I try to copy the log from my raspberry pi but as I am using ssh and putty can't let me see what I can do

Comment: added more logs, seems to be getting stuck on a frame each time

Comment: @ysoulja  You have a lot of dropped frames. What is your ISP advertised upload speed? If you need to go lower you can try using a peak constrained bitrate by setting `-b:v 700k  -maxrate 700k -bufsize 700k`

Comment: It looks like you aren't streaming anything past frame 98. Note the frame=, and the steadily dropping fps. Looks like YouTube is right, they are not getting your data. I don't know exactly why this is happening.

Comment: aergistal - ISP upload speed ~5Mbps
bodangly - it is quite weird.

I purchased a Raspberry Pi Camera v2 Module - I have just plugged that in and ran and have managed at 1280 x 720 which makes this even more odd, as that suggest not a upload speed issue - maybe hardware problem?

Comment: `raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -b 4000000 -g 50 | ./ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<stream nameid>` is what I used for the Raspberry Pi v2 Camera

Comment: @shellter - that is true. I have flagged it. Thank you